# Making Loops in CMD

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to create a loop in CMD, that runs a command (or set of commands). I've looked around, but there isn't really a good instruction manual or place to start. Any help on making loops and executing commands in CMD is appreciated.
This is the code I am currently using:

```
for /l %stuff IN (1,1,10) DO start
```

I am expecting 10 CMD windows to pop up, by using a for loop that runs a 'start' command 10 times.
Instead, I get:

```
%stuff was unexpected at this time
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Loop variables are limited to one (1) letter. When writing loops in a .bat or .cmd script file, the `%` on variables must be doubled. `for /l %%s IN (1,1,10) DO start` Use `FOR /?` to learn about creating loops. That is the starting point you seek.

Comment: Reading the help helps a lot -- type `for /?` into a command prompt window and check out the output...

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly then I think I have a simple solution. Start of with `:whatever title you want` at the top of the command prompt, then after put in any commands you want to run under it, and at the end of the command prompt put in `goto :whatever title you want` if the name after the `:` is the same, then it should go through all the commands you put in.

```
:your title
command
command
goto :your title
```

Comment: Note: a label can't have a space. The label is just `:your` , the rest is ignored. (same with `goto`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create loops on cmd like this;

```
for /l %a in (1,1,10) do @echo %a
```

Besides you can execute some commands. Here is an example;

```
for /l %a in (1,1,7) do @color &a && timeout 1
```

An other example you can check empty IP addresses. For example i want to check the IP adresses between 192.168.1.60 - 192.168.1.70 and which ones are in use;

```
for /l %a in (60,1,70) do @ping 192.168.1.%a
```

And you can do infinite loop if you require it. For example you want to check IP address returns from some site. In normal conditions you do

```
ping abc.com -t
```

But this is always pings and you need to stop it with ctrl+c and restart it. To get rid of this you can use for loop on cmd and handle it like this;

```
for /l %a in (1,0,2) do @ping abc.com
```

So ping works 4 times, finishes and restarts on an infinite loop. All you need to do is stop the loop with ctrl+c if command execution is enough.